# WorldToScreen function

Tags: math, vector, 3d, geometry, unreal

I am creating a mod for an UnrealEngine game. Sadly the worldtoscreen function in my SDK is broken. Im using CodeRedGenerator and the game is Rocket Legaue. Canvas.Project always returns (0,0,0) for me. if u have any fixes for that let me know.
anyways i decided to write my own world_to_screen

Given parameters i have:
-vector point position in world
-camera position vector
-camera FOV

- camera view angle defined by pitch, yaw and roll

and of course i need screenPosition coordinates

also i already hav a function which converts pitch, yaw and roll to a viewdirection vector.

but sadly i suck at maths and have no idea what to do at this point.

can anyone who is smart either tell me what to do or give me resources where i can find such a function.

i appreciate any help <3

Comment: You might want to also ask this over on the [gamedev.se] site.